# How to pass custom values to an email template using the API?

Tags: soap-api, marketing-cloud

This question regarding Exact Target SOAP API. How to pass values to an email template using the API?

Thanks,

Comment: Which question would you prefer to have answered here?  Also do you have any SOAP API calls you have tried yet, or are you just asking for the code sample?

Comment: I'll answer the title question, please ask the second as a separate question.

Comment: Make sure to remove the second portion of the question, as the two are separate items and need to be addressed this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample SOAP envelope from the [documentation](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/send_triggeredsend_email/)- this envelope is for a triggered send.  You will need to have the personalization string in your template like `%%MyAttributeName%%`.  Your attribute will need to allow [updates at send time](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/profile_and_preference_attributes/).

```
<soap:Body>
  <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <Options/>
     <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSend">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <TriggeredSendDefinition>
           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
           <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
           <CustomerKey>Definition_Key</CustomerKey>
        </TriggeredSendDefinition>
        <Subscribers>
           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
           <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
           <EmailAddress>aruiz@example.com</EmailAddress>
           <SubscriberKey>aruiz@example.com</SubscriberKey>
           <Attributes>
              <Name>MyAttributeName</Name>
              <Value>MyAttributeValue</Value>
           </Attributes>
        </Subscribers>
     </Objects>
  </CreateRequest>
```